# PropertyGrid does not update after changing a property

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

In my WPF project I'm using a PropertyGrid. I set the SelectedObject and data is correctly visualized.

I've also added the following to allow that, if user changes value of one of the properties inside the SelectedObject, some properties will be hidden and others are shown

```
 PropertyDescriptorCollection pdcSld = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.sld.GetType());

 PropertyDescriptor descriptorF0 = pdcSld["f0Sld"];
 PropertyDescriptor descriptortcStar = pdcSld["tcStarSSld"];
 PropertyDescriptor descriptorGammaI = pdcSld["gammaI"];
 PropertyDescriptor descriptorSpectrum = pdcSld["spectrum"];

 if (descriptorF0 != null)
 {
     BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptorF0.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
     FieldInfo isBrow = attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    isBrow.SetValue(attrib, true);
                }

                if (descriptortcStar != null)
                {
                    BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptortcStar.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
                    FieldInfo isBrow =
                      attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    isBrow.SetValue(attrib, true);
                }

                if (descriptorGammaI != null)
                {
                    BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptorGammaI.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
                    FieldInfo isBrow =
                      attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    isBrow.SetValue(attrib, false);
                }

                if (descriptorSpectrum != null)
                {
                    BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptorSpectrum.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
                    FieldInfo isBrow =
                      attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    isBrow.SetValue(attrib, false);
                }
```

When I open the window in which PropertyGrid is shown, everything works as expected, that is that some values are shown or hidden accordingly to the value of a certain property.

If user changes that value in PropertyGrid, code is called but the grid does not refreshes and remains as it was before the modification.

I've also tried with adding

```
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
```

before the property that could raise the refresh of grid (change visibility), but it does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ought to be tricky.  Try re-assigning the SelectedObject property.

Comment: How to do it if I do modification of BrowsableAttribute inside a setter of object? I cannot use from there the PropertyGrid...

Comment: Nobody could help me about this?